# How to best detect if my website is being accessed through mobile device

Tags: javascript, python, mobile, browser

I have a python based website (on app-engine). What this means is my server is written in python and I am using the usual webapp2 and jinja2 to help serve my pages. What I want to accomplish is that depending on whether someone is accessing my website through iPhone, Android, or a normal computer (i.e. desktop or laptop) to server the webpage in appropriate "format". I supposed there are many ways I can do this

1. I could do it through JavaScript and then redirect to the appropriate "mobile" url
2. Or I can do it in Python and serve the correct page

What I mean in `2` is something like

```
class ServeMyPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
      //...do some work to determine the device, such as screen size
      if device==iPhone
        //...get the iPhone page and serve it
        self.response.out.write(iPhonePage);
      else ...// etc, etc
```

In my snippet I am doing it before serving the page. I imagine this is faster as it does not wait for the page to load and then check with some JavaScript to see if I should change the content to the appropriate format. I hope this is clear.

So what is the best way to do this? Should I do it in JavaScript? some other way? or as I show above? If as I show above, what might the code look like? My problem is also technical in that I don't know what code to put in the Python. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**modernizr's**](http://modernizr.com/) touch detection in order to check if it's a touch device, and, if yes, you have one point for mobile.

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {

}
else 
{
    code for non mobile device
}
```

Then, you can check for the user agent (this might not be your best option as user agent isn't always reliable), and write a simple if else, with the code to be executed only on non mobile devices in the else

```
  var isMobile = {
            Android: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
            },
            BlackBerry: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
            },
            iOS: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
            },
            Opera: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
            },
            Windows: function () {
                return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
            },
            any: function () {
                return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
            }
        };

        if (isMobile.any()) {

        }
        else {

             not mobile
        }
```

Another way of testing would be by checking window.innerWidth and only init your script if the screen size is larger than 760px:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 760) {
not mobile
}
```

A good way to do this would be to combine the 3 statements above to check.

Comment: So you are suggesting using JavaScript. But I was told that checking at the JavaScript level will introduce lag in the loading speed. So do you know a way to do it at the python/server level?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with python. All I can say is that I don't see a loading speed lag for my applications when using above mentionend methods. If there is a speed decrease it's very marginal I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

you can use WURFL APIs to detect device type

http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/wurfl_schema.php

Comment: A full list of capabilities to query can be found here: http://www.scientiamobile.com/wurflCapability